# How to find acceleration given power, velocity and mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, acceleration, velocity, power

Suppose we have an ideal vehicle with mass $m$ and power output $P$. Under ideal conditions, without friction, when the engine is running, $P$ is the time derivative of the kinetic energy of the vehicle $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. By taking the derivative w.r.t. time on this last equation we get
$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{d(v^2)}{dt}$$
$$P=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{d(v^2)}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$P=\frac{1}{2}m\cdot 2v\cdot a$$
$$P=mva$$
$$a=\frac{P}{mv}$$

What does this mean when $v=0$? I am clearly getting this wrong; what is the correct formula to find the acceleration given power, velocity and mass?

Please note that I don't need to get the full evolution over time of $a(t)$, it suffices to know $a$ at the current instant, from the values of $P$ and $m$ (which are fixed for the vehicle) and the instantaneous value of $v$. Also assume the motion of this vehicle is 1-dimensional, so all values are scalar.

Comment: I believe the power can only be constant if the kinetic energy is linear in $t$, up to an additive constant. Now if $E(t) = \frac{1}{2} m (A t + B)$ if and only if $v(t) = \pm \sqrt{A t+B}$. The acceleration is then determined, except for the parameter $B$ that you cannot express through $P$.

Comment: Indifferently of the fact that you can determine $B$ or not, the acceleration would be $a(t) = \pm \frac{A}{2\sqrt{A t + B}} = \frac{A}{2 v(t)}$, which makes patent that the acceleration must diverge as $v\to 0$ in this case.